# Programing an STM32F4 with OpenOCD on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi4, stm32f4, openocd

I'm trying to flash the bootloader on an STM32F407 via the SWD interface, the board in question is the Makerbase Robin Nano v3 this is a 3d printer controller board.

I have OpenOCD running fine on my Raspberry Pi 4 and I'm able to read sectors of the internal memory

The problem is that I can't write, and I'm not sure why.

I tried a simple test with

```
READ  -> stm32f4.cpu mdb 0x8000000 -> output: 0xFF
WRITE -> stm32f4.cpu mwb 0x8000000 0xAA -> no output
READ  -> stm32f4.cpu mdb 0x8000000 -> output: 0xFF // didn't change
```

Writing specific bytes doesn't seem to work.

If I try to program it with `load_image` this is the output

```
> load_image nano_v3_bootloader.bin 0x8000000     
SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Failed to write memory and, additionally, failed to find out where

SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
```

If I try to program it with `program` this is the output

```
> program nano_v3_bootloader.bin 0x8000000
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xfffffffc
** Programming Started **
SWD DPIDR 0xdeadbeef
Failed to write memory and, additionally, failed to find out where
error writing to flash at address 0x08000000 at offset 0x00000000
embedded:startup.tcl:308: Error: auto erase enabled

at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 308
```

I'm brand new to ARM my guess is that maybe the bootloader is locked ( I tried to unlock it with stm32f4x unlock 0, didn't seem to make a difference), or I'm doing something in the wrong order or missing a step somewhere.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong

This is my openocd.cfg

```
source [find interface/raspberrypi2-native.cfg]
transport select swd

set CHIPNAME stm32f4
source [find target/stm32f4x.cfg]

# did not yet manage to make a working setup using srst
#reset_config srst_only
reset_config  srst_nogate

adapter_nsrst_delay 100
adapter_nsrst_assert_width 100

init
targets
reset halt
```

And this is my raspberrypi2_native.cfg

```
#
# Config for using Raspberry Pi's expansion header
#
# This is best used with a fast enough buffer but also
# is suitable for direct connection if the target voltage
# matches RPi's 3.3V and the cable is short enough.
#
# Do not forget the GND connection, pin 6 of the expansion header.
#

adapter driver bcm2835gpio

bcm2835gpio_peripheral_base 0xFE000000

# Transition delay calculation: SPEED_COEFF/khz - SPEED_OFFSET
# These depend on system clock, calibrated for stock 700MHz
# bcm2835gpio_speed SPEED_COEFF SPEED_OFFSET
bcm2835gpio_speed_coeffs 236181 60

# Each of the JTAG lines need a gpio number set: tck tms tdi tdo
# Header pin numbers: 23 22 19 21
bcm2835gpio_jtag_nums 11 25 10 9

# Each of the SWD lines need a gpio number set: swclk swdio
# Header pin numbers: 23 22
bcm2835gpio_swd_nums 25 24

# If you define trst or srst, use appropriate reset_config
# Header pin numbers: TRST - 26, SRST - 18

# bcm2835gpio_trst_num 7
# reset_config trst_only

bcm2835gpio_srst_num 18
reset_config srst_only srst_push_pull

# or if you have both connected,
# reset_config trst_and_srst srst_push_pull
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running these commands fixed the problem

```
> flash erase_sector 0 0 11 // this will erase bank 0
> flash write_bank 0 nano_v3_bootloader.bin 0 // this will write the bin file to the bank 0
```

Comment: how are you connecting the RPI4 to the STM32 MCU? GPIO25 and 24 to SWDCLK and SWDIO, only? Or do you also have reset connected? I'm trying without success to flash an STM32F411